# Probability of succesful rolls of different sided dies

Tags: probability, dice

This seems so simple, but I'm not sure how to calculate it.

I have one six-sided die and one 12-sided die.

What is the probability that, on a roll of both dice, that the six-sided die will win?

I'm not overly familiar with mathematical notation. Thank you!

Comment: Just one poor little six-sided? I assume wins means **greater**. Then the probability is $(1/6)(0/12)+(1/6)(1/12)+(1/6)(2/12)+(1/6)(3/12)+(1/6)(4/12)+(1/6)(5/12)$.  This simplifies to $5/24$.

Comment: Similarly, the probability of a tie is $6(1/6)(1/12)=2/24$ and the probability of a loss is $17/24$, so if you roll again after a tie then the probability of the six-sided die eventually winning is $5/22$

Answer (score 0):

The number of possibilities is 6 * 12 (every combination of a six sided dice and a 12 sided dice).

The general way to do this, particularly for such a small problem space is to list out every possible combination, make rectangular table with 12 entries on one side and 6 entries on the other and fill in who "wins," sum up the winners for each side and divide by 72 (the total number of possibilities).

In a comment above it's shown how to do this more simply, but this is the general solution to these sorts of problems.